# JSON ou SQLite?

Tags: json, sqlite, apache-cordova

Estou desenvolvendo um app simples em `PhoneGap` e vou precisar ter basicamente 2 tabelas. Uma para armazenar os nomes das séries e outra para armazenar os exercícios de cada série específica. Mas não sei bem como funciona tanto o `JSON` como o `SQLite`, gostaria de saber se pra uma informação tão simples, qual seria melhor para se utilizar.

Comment: É difícil comparar os dois, pois um é um formato de arquivos e o outro é um banco de dados... Qual é sua principal dificuldade? Ou seu principal objetivo? (tipo: facilidade pra gerar/interpretar os dados, facilidade para salvar/alterar/excluir no disco, etc) Tem experiência com SQL?

Comment: Minha dificuldade é saber como vou poder tratar esses dados de maneira mais simples, já que vou ter que usar JS pra isso, já tenho uma certa experiência com SQL sim, mas nunca fiz algo utilizando JS.

Meu maior problema é como poder tratar esses dados.

Comment: Vou deixar quem tem experiência em PhoneGap responder, então. Pois de fato, é muito fácil tratar dados JSON em JavaScript, mas você teria que fazer a persistência dos mesmos na mão. Por outro lado, é muito fácil fazer a persistência via SQL, mas você teria de tratar dos dados na mão...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A principal diferença dessas duas abordagens é que se você for usar JSON (e gravar em um arquivo local, usando as APIs de I/O do PhoneGap), você está responsável por decidir como armazenar / ler esta informação no sistema de arquivos local - e dependendo de como você gravar os dados a forma de acessá-los irá variar bastante.

Tipicamente, usar JSON para armazenar dados funciona bem quando você pode gravar e ler *todos os dados de uma vez (*)* - você serializa (e.g., `JSON.stringify`) o objeto (ou array) que contem os seus dados, e grava tudo em um arquivo local. Quando precisar acessar o dado, você lê o arquivo local e carrega todos os dados na memória. Se quiser acessar apenas parte do dado, ainda assim (neste exemplo) você teria que carregar todos os dados na memória. Para inserir / atualizar / remover uma linha da tabela (e.g., uma série de exercícios), você adicionaria / modificaria / removeria ela do array em memória e, novamente, grava todo o arquivo.

Se usar um banco de dados, como SQLite, você tem mais controle sobre o que será acessado em disco. Você pode ler apenas uma parte da tabela, editar / remover apenas uma linha da tabela.

A melhor solução é geralmente a mais simples que funciona para o seu cenário. Se a quantidade de informação que será armazenada no cliente é pequena o suficiente (e a definição de "pequena o suficiente" depende de fatores como quantidade de dados, memória dos dispositivos onde você imagina que a sua applicação irá rodar, etc.), que possa ser sempre carregada em memória sem problemas, então usar o sistema de arquivos diretamente via as tabelas JSON-ificadas é uma boa solução. Se o custo de ter todos os objetos em memória é muito alto, ou se você precisa de outras *features* de um banco de dados (e.g., indíces para performance de buscas, simplicidade em realizar *JOIN*'s, etc.), então usar um BD (como SQLite) é mais vantajoso.

(*) O seu caso parece ser mais simples que o caso geral - você tem duas tabelas (relação 1:n, pelo que entendi), então você pode diminuir alguma das limitações da opção de sistema de arquivos. Por exemplo, você pode ter um arquivo (que seria lido em memória) com o nome das séries, e um dos campos do objeto armazenado naquele arquivo seria o nome de outro arquivo que contém os exercícios para aquela série, e algum outro campo pelo qual você queira fazer buscas (e.g., data da série). Somente quando a aplicação precisar acessar os dados de séries específicas é que você precisaria fazer a leitura delas para memória, e você também pode editar / adicionar / remover séries específicas sem ter que sempre gravar / carregar todo o seu "banco de dados".

Comment: Carlos, muito boa sua explicação. Esclareceu todas as minhas dúvidas em relação a isso. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Algumas pessoas diriam que o mais simples é o SQLite em qualquer situação para evitar você ter que lidar com tudo o que é necessário para garantir o bom funcionamento do arquivo *flat*. A maioria dos programadores nem sabe tudo o que pode dar errado. E se o programador tem experiência com SQL, pode ser mais fácil ainda. Fazer algo diferente do que está acostumado não costuma ser a solução mais simples, mesmo quando ela por si só seja simples. Não estou discordando da resposta, apenas colocando um ponto adicional a considerar.